# Preserve selection between UICollectionViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm developing an iOS app using Swift 2.0. Actually I'm facing a problem using `UICollectionViewControllers` to select multiple cells and preserve selection.

What I'm trying to do is to provide the user to select their images from Camera Roll, Facebook or Instagram. So far, I present the photo albums to the user in a `PhotoAlbumsTableViewController` and show the images in a `PhotoCollectionViewController` after the user select an album. Everything is working correctly until now.

Now, I want to preserve the selected photos on each album after the user returns to the `AlbumsViewController` to allow the user to select multiple photos on the `Camera Roll` then get back and select some others on the `Instagram` album and then click a `Done` button to show all the selected images. Any ideas?

Thanks in regards.

Comment: While navigating from that view controller simply store the selection indexes in an array and creat new NSUserDefault with that array. When ever you are back to that view controller you can get the selction array from user defaults and set them back

Comment: Can you provide some sample code please? I'm new on swift